# How to add my own activity in Android/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-source

I'm trying to add my own ConfirmDialog.java in AOSP /frameworks/base/core/java/android/app directory. I will need to launch the ConfirmDialog later from /frameworks/base/core/java/android/my_module/my_class.java.
To start ConfirmDialog.java from my_class.java, the code snippet is as follows:

```
  Intent resolveActivityIntent = new Intent();
  resolveActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  resolveActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION); // indicate target activity is not launched by user manually

  ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("android.app", "android.app.ConfirmDialog");
  resolveActivityIntent.setComponent(comp);
  ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().startActivityAndWait(null, null, resolveActivityIntent, null, null, null, 0, resolveActivityIntent.getFlags(), null, null, null, UserHandle.USER_CURRENT);
```

The AOSP compiles successfully. However, when the "startActivityAndWait(...)" is called, the emulator will crash and Logcat will give me the following error:

```
12-10 17:46:14.811: V/PackageManager(758): getActivityInfo ComponentInfo{android.app/android.app.DatePickerDialog}: null
12-10 17:46:14.831: E/AndroidRuntime(758): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: PackageManager
12-10 17:46:14.831: E/AndroidRuntime(758): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.applicationInfo' on a null object reference
12-10 17:46:14.831: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resolveActivity(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:599)
```

I'm guessing this error popups because I didn't register ConfirmDialog.java successfully in *.mk. Not sure, though. I tried to figure out how the other classes in the same directory are used but with no luck, I couldn't find any reference to similar usage. Anybody has similar experience, please help me a little bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an old thread and I don't know if you are still stuck here, but you or anyone else might take a look at [this link](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_adding_your_own_app)

Sorry for digging up 'old' threads :D

Comment: I've solved the issue but not have time to write down my solution yet. I think your link will help followers. Thanks for your answer!